# SVN doesn't ask for authentication on checkin/checkout

Tags: linux, svn, authentication

I have installed SVN on a CENTOS 5 server running WHM/cPanel.

The SVN URL works fine and asks for a password as expected. However when running the svn checkout command or commit command from my local machine authentication is not requested thus allowing anyone to access the SVN repo.

My svn.conf is as follows:

```
<Location /repos>
DAV svn
SVNPath /home/<user>/repo

Require valid-user

AuthType Basic
AuthName "DEV REPO"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
</Location>
```

I used htpasswd to create a user in the file /etc/svn-auth-conf. I then used avnadmin to create a repo at /home//repo and chmod'd and chown'd it to the

Thanks.

(P.s. i followed this guide: http://sven.webiny.com/subversion-on-cpanel-3-with-centos-55-and-easyapache-32/)

Comment: Just to clarify: you created a repo at `/home/repo` or `/home/<user>/repo`. And what URL did you use to checkout?

Comment: For more clarification: You are trying to checkout the repo using the svn checkout svn://svnrepo.com/here command from the command line on your local machine?  Did you setup authentication in the svnserve.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but have you tried clearing the cached auth data in ./subversion/auth? If this is the case, you may want to disable caching by modifying the values of store-passwords/store-auth-creds.